# Multilingual pages links showing node instead of URL alias

Tags: 7, path-aliases, uri

My web has 2 languages, English and Malay. The language selection is by session of `?lang=en` or `?lang=ms`.

English is the default language and it is working fine. All internal links are using the correct URL aliases. The problem arises when switching to Malay language. All links became node/(some-number).

For example:
About Us Page
all using about-us as URL Alias

In English
www.example.com/about-us

In Malay
www.example.com/node/2

Even when I type out the URL `www.example.com/about-us?lang=ms` it doesn't work. It will still show the English language.

Answer (score 0):

Add translation in Malay language for about-us node and add alias to it. When node hasn't translation to Malay language, it will be without alias when You change lng

Comment: Yup, I have already added the alias for Malay language. Both English and Malay are pointing to about-us URL alias, but only English is showing correctly, Malay is still wrong.